# Trying to bind a value from database in already existing dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to bind a value from database in an already existing dropdown list.
the dropdown list

```
<select class='form-control' id='P_Group'>
   <option value='HB'>HB</option>
   <option value='SPRING'>SPRING</option>
   <option value='PC'>PC</option>
</select>
```

sending it db like this

```
 var user = {};
user.P_GROUP = $("[id*=P_Group]").val();
```

Now want to bind the value which is saved in database to this another in dropdown

```
<select class='form-control' id='lblP_Groupn' runat="server">
   <option value='HB' runat="server">HB</option>
   <option value='SPRING' runat="server">SPRING</option>
   <option value='PC' runat="server">PC</option>
</select>
```

Like this shown below after reading data

```
while (ReadData.Read())
   {lblP_Groupn.DataValueField= ReadData["p_group"].ToString();
}
```

But default value which has been saved in the database is not seen while binding. it is again showing a dropdown with all the options.I want the saved option to be seen by default. and again he can select any option in it.Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `DataSource`, `DataTextField`,`DataValueField` and `DataBind()` to fill values in `HtmlSelect`.

Or use `HtmlSelect.Items.Add()` to add values to existing dropdown with existing values.

After you are done adding items, use `Items` again to find the value and mark selected.

Change  code to

```
while (ReadData.Read())
{
     lblP_Groupn.Items.Add(new ListItem(ReadData["p_group"].ToString(), ReadData["p_group"].ToString()));
}
```

Now use

```
var item = lblPGroupn.Items.FindByValue(SOMEVALUE);
if(item!=null)
{
    item.Selected=true;
}
```

Comment: i want the same value which was selected earlier to be bind directly and should be seen by default.so how can i put that value in place of 'SOMEVALUE'

Comment: Since you want to show selected item from one dropdown P_Group into lblPGroupn then SOMEVALUE should be SelectedValue of P_Group. If this is not what you want to do then kindly rephrase your question.